# Modifying a structure member with pointers in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to assign a value to a member of a structure in a very roundabout way. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. In main, create an array of structure pointers.
2. (Still in main) Pass a pointer to that array to a function.
3. Inside the function, create a structure and add a pointer to it to the array.
4. (Still inside function) Assign a value to a member of the structure that was just created.

I'm very new to C, so I don't have a very good understanding of pointers. I thought that this process would allow me to see the value that was assigned from main, but when I print it it appears to be empty. What am I doing wrong (barring the obvious - I'm making this way too complicated)?
Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct MyStruct {
    char name[9];
};

void give_name(struct MyStruct ** structlist_ptr) {
    struct MyStruct new_struct;
    structlist_ptr[0] = &new_struct;
    strcpy(structlist_ptr[0]->name, "confused");
}

int main(void) {
    struct MyStruct * struct_list[1];

    give_name(struct_list);
    printf("%s\n", struct_list[0]->name); /* Appears to print random characters */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `give_name` you create a temporary MyStruct object on the stack, which imediately get invalid after the the function returns. Now you have a dangling pointer in main::struct_list[0], which is undefined behaviour, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The major problem is this assignment:

```
structlist_ptr[0] = &new_struct;
```

With that you make `*structlist_ptr` (the usual way to use "reference" pointers) point to the ***local*** variable `new_struct`.

Once the function returns, the life-time of the local variables will end as they go out of scope. They will, in a manner of speaking, cease to exist. That leaves you with a stray and invalid pointer. Attempting to dereference it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Man, I can't believe I didn't think about that, thank you so much! In the more fleshed-out version of this, I'm basically trying to append new structure pointers to the array with the function. I realize I could do this by making new_struct, global, but I'm hesitant to do that. I also don't want to pass it in to the function from main. Is there a better way?

Comment: I also just realized that either of the methods I mentioned above wouldn't work, since it would always point to the same struct. Is there any way to add a new struct to the array every time the function is called?

Comment: @maknel Yes, you can use [malloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate memory on the heap.